# Rails 4 beta1 install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im having trouble getting the Rails 4 beta installed.  I used RVM to install Ruby 2.0.0 and that seems to have succeeded ok.  Here is the error I get when attempting to install the Rails gem;

```
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0.beta1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing your RVM rubies with the latest versions should enable you to load all the dependencies required to install Rails:

```
rvm get head --autolibs=3
rvm pkg remove
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Comment: Finally got it to work.  It had trouble with openssl for some reason, I followed a few rabbit trails but this is what I think fixed it;

    rvm pkg install openssl : 

    brew update (im on a Mac) : 

    rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr : 

Then the gem install rails worked.  
Thanks for your help, it got me going down the right path.